# What does the samples and value signify in this Random Forest tree Node

Tags: python, tree, nodes, random-forest

Can you tell me what the "samples" and "value" in this `split node` from a `Random Forest` tree means?

Here is the node:

[image]

Comment: Which library are you using to run or print this? Maybe a look in its documentation will help you

Comment: You can learn more about random forest [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/understanding-random-forest/), it might help

Comment: @nikitira, I am using the `scikit-learn` library.  I looked at the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html but could not see much on the questions that I asked.

Comment: @Salahuddin, that link does not answer my question. Thanks!